# Correctly sink click event

Tags: gwt, dom

I'm trying to create an expandable and selectable row element in GWT. This row contains an expand icon which I can click on to expand the row. I can also click on each row to select it.

My problem is that if I click on the expand icon I always trigger the row selection event too and I don't want that. How can I sink the click event so that if I click on the expand icon, only the expand will occur, but not the selection?

The green row is selected:

[image: A row selected]

When I expand a row I also trigger the selection with the click and my selection move(bad):

[image]

This is what I want: I expand with the plus icon, without changing in the selection(yay!) :

[image]

I tried to use `expandIcon.sinkEvent(Event.ONCLICK);` but it didn't help. How can I do this?

Comment: Is `expandIcon` a child of the row? I'm not sure it's possible to exclude a child from its parent's events without writing your own Javascript/native method to do this.

Comment: Yes, the row is a `HorizontalPanel` and the icon is the first widget in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent widget, you'd want to [`stopPropagation()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#stopPropagation%28%29) when handling it at the `expandIcon` level.